# jQuery strange behavior in seperate .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, external, behavior

My index.html includes both the jQuery.js and my own script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jQuery/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
```

myscript.js looks like this:

```
function eval() {
    document.getElementById("rContent").innerHTML = "<ul id=\"agentList\">";
    var agentNames = $( ".tttAgentName" );
    var falloutOrders = $( ".tttFalloutOrder" );

    var i, j = 0;   
    for(i = 0, j = 0; i < agentNames.length, j < falloutOrders.length; i++, j++) {
        document.getElementById("agentList").innerHTML += "<li>" + agentNames[i].value + ": ";
        document.getElementById("agentList").innerHTML += falloutOrders[j].value + "</li><br/>";
    }

    document.getElementById("rContent").innerHTML += "</ul>";
}
```

What I don't quite understand here is this:
While the two jQuery-selectors $( ".tttAgentName" ) and $( ".tttFalloutOrder" ) have been working all along, I'm forced to do the rest with standard JavaScript. For Instance, if I change

```
document.getElementById("agentList").innerHTML
```

to

```
$( "#agentList" ).html
```

the script stops working.

Using the normal JavaScript selectors, the script works just fine.

I'm sure it's something rather trivial, but what am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You need to wait for jQuery to be loaded. So in your myscript.js file just put all of that in a $(document).ready(function(){ ... });

Comment: If that is truly the contents of myscript.js, you're changing the existing `window.eval` function to your own... something you may want to reconsider.

Comment: @Josh thank you that was the solution to the script not executing properly - put everything into $(document).ready() and now it executes.

Comment: @Mike wow no I don't want that - replaced the name, thanks for the warning!

Answer (score 3):

[jQuery's .html](https://api.jquery.com/html/) is a function...not a property:

```
$( "#agentList" ).html()
```

Invoking it without params returns the current value.  Invoking it with params replaces the current html.

Comment: `.html` is a method and it's a property, but setting the property will simple replace the method rater than setting the innerHTML.

Comment: Yes I meant the jQuery function html(). - Actually replaced it with $.append() now since I wanted to preserve any html-content in the same container I would append my new html to. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @NULL yes, that is true. However, the point is that calling $( "#agentList" ).html without parentheses just returns the function definition...not the html of the selected element(s).